# Not scrolling to indicated position in rebuilt page

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to scroll to a specific place in my (newly built) page from the (same) page (with different content). AngularJS builds the new page, but doesn't scroll (at all) down to the desired location.

I have a page, *./index.html*, that, depending on links clicked, loads content from one of many individual, simple HTML files. Internally to any given content, I can create references between locations using a function, *gotoLocation()* and these work. However, scrolling to a location deep inside another content does not work, only that content is loaded and its top is displayed.

For example, in *./glossary.html* is:

```
|p|
Here is an "internal" hypertext link to go to
|a href="" ng-click="gotoLocation( 'relationship' )"||i|relationship|/i||/a|
in the Glossary.
|/p|
.
.
.
|a id="relationship"||/a|
|p|
relationship - the quality of a connection colored as "success", "failure"
or any other designation as conceived by the processor's author.
|/p|
```

And, when the glossary is loaded, clicking on that link does scroll down to the desired location. But, if that link is in another content (say, *./concepts.html*), I still wish it to land down inside the glossary (*./glossary.html*), so I do this in *./concepts.html*:

```
|p|
Here is an "external" hypertext link to go to
|a href="" ng-click="gotoPageAndLocation( './glossary.html', 'relationship' )"|
|i|relationship|/i||/a| in the Glossary on a "different" page (that is, in
different content than the content this link is in).
|/p|
```

The JS functions I have are:

```
angular.module( 'anchorScrollModule', [] )
.controller( 'ScrollController', [ '$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
'$http', '$timeout',
function( $scope, $location, $anchorScroll, $http, $timeout )
{
    $scope.gotoLocation = function( where )
    {
      $location.hash( where );
      $anchorScroll();
    }

    $scope.gotoPage = function( page )
    {
      $scope.filepath = page;
    }

    $scope.gotoPageAndLocation = function( page, where )
    {
      $scope.filepath = page;

      waitForRenderAndGotoReference( where );
    }

    /* Wait for the AngularJS digest cycle. See
     * http://tech.endeepak.com/blog/2014/05/03/waiting-for-angularjs-digest-cycle/
     * (However, pendingRequests.length is always 0 anyway!!!!)
     */
    waitForRenderAndGotoReference = function( where )
    {
      console.log( "Pending requests length: " + $http.pendingRequests.length );

      if( $http.pendingRequests.length > 0 )
      {
         $timeout( waitForRenderAndGotoReference( where ) );
      }
      else
      {
         $location.hash( where );
         $anchorScroll();
      }
    }
}]);
```